# Flutter mailer is sending duplicate emails, two at the same time

Tags: flutter, email, mailer

I have to build an app with a send email function and i decided to use mailer. But after testing I get two identical emails and I put one more email to cc and that email also received two emails. Is there a way so that my app will send only one email and not two?

```
void _mailer() async {

String username = '**@gmail.com';

String password = '**';

final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

final message = Message()

  ..from = Address(username, 'Your name')
  ..recipients.add('**@outlook.com')
  ..ccRecipients.add('**@yahoo.com')
  ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}'
  ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
  ..attachments = attachments;

try {
  final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
  print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
} on MailerException catch (e) {
  print('Message not sent.');
  for (var p in e.problems) {
    print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
  }
}

var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

await connection.send(message);

await connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this function sends 1 email:

```
try {
 final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
  print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
} on MailerException catch (e) {
  print('Message not sent.');
  for (var p in e.problems) {
    print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
  }
}
```

And these 3 lines of code are sending the second email:

```
var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

await connection.send(message);

await connection.close();
```

So I just deleted the last 3 lines of code and now my app is sending just one email